# My div not take the width of parents in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

one div and i check to the div width in jquery and same width i define in next div but width not apear in my div please help me

**my code is this**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var widthRP = $('.jsPanelWidth').width();
  $(window).load(function(){
    $('.jsRgtPnl').css("width":"widthRP"+"px");
  })
});
```

Comment: Next time, you can check the javascript console by pressing F12, and going to console, as well as right clicking on the element and selecting "Inspect Element" to see what the attribute was set to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to use dom ready and window load handler together

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $('.jsRgtPnl').width($('.jsPanelWidth').width());
})
```

Comment: this is the window load if i m resize the window than i can define this width

Comment: @RohitAzad if you want to execute the code on window resize then look at the [resize](http://api.jquery.com/resize/) event

Answer (score 2):

use `$('.jsRgtPnl').css("width", widthRP+"px");` instead of `$('.jsRgtPnl').css("width":"widthRP"+"px");`

Answer (score 2):

Simple mistake, you're passing "widthRP" as a string not a variable. Remove the quotes and change to a `,` because you're passing two strings, not an object.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var widthRP = $('.jsPanelWidth').width();
  $(window).load(function(){
    $('.jsRgtPnl').css("width",widthRP+"px");
  })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `,` instead of `:` and do not wrap the variable name with brackets:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var widthRP = $('.jsPanelWidth').width();
  $(window).load(function(){
    $('.jsRgtPnl').css("width", widthRP+"px");
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the double codes from widthRP in load function because its a variable and you are using it as string and use , instead of :. Hope this will help you.